# Function not working inside prepend in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="playlist_item">
    <ul class="link" id="link">
        <div class="style"><input type="checkbox" class="styled">
            <div id="style"></div>   
        </div>
        <li class="edit">http://carouselinfo.com/canal/</li>
        <span class="main edit">123</span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I prepend ie add the ul element then my other jquery event for this element not working

Jquery code:

```
$(function() {    
    $(".new").click(function(){
    $("#playlist_item").prepend("<ul class='link' id='link'><div class='style'><input type='checkbox' class='styled'><div id='style'></div></div><li class='edit'>Please edit this file</li><span class='main edit'>Write Duration</span></ul>")
});
```

This code is not working for prepend elements

```
$('.edit').editable();

$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var check_all = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    if ($(this).closest("ul").hasClass("change_link")) {
        $(this).closest("ul").removeClass("change_link");
    } else {
        $(this).closest("ul").addClass("change_link");
        $(".option").html("<div id='icons'><div class='add'></div></div><div id='icons'><div class='delete'></div></div>");
    }

    if (check_all.length == $("input[type='checkbox']").not(":checked").length) {
        $(".option").html("");
    }
});
```

Where I am wrong? Please help me out..

Comment: I think click handlers need to be re-applied every time you manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I think that, in your HTML, the `<div>`s and `<span>` inside the `<ul>` should be nested inside the `<li>` tag. Probably not the source of your problem, but it's more correct.

Comment: @Blazemonger ok I will do..but what for my jquery problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$('input:checkbox').click(function() {` with the following code:

```
$('#playlist_item').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
```

When binding the event to `$('input:checkbox')` it will only be bound to matching element that exist at the moment where you perform the binding. By using the delegate syntax you bind the event to a parent element and thus receive the events from all child elements, even if they did not exist when calling the `.on()` function.

Since you also want to call `.editable()` on the new elements, do the following after adding a new one:

```
$('.edit:not(.editable-done)').addClass('editable-done').editable();
```

This will ensure `.editable()` is only called once per element. In case it is a jQuery UI widget you can simply keep `$('.edit').editable()` though - they detect automatically if the widget has already been created or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster-what about edit.editable(); it is a jquery function which edit by adding inline textbox how this will work?

Comment: Ah, didn't notice `.edit` is also inside that string. Answer updated.

Comment: it's not working actually editable is taken from http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable how can I run for new element I add.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqRQN/ this is js file which I am calling in html file using $('.edit').editable() but it is not working when calling $('#playlist_item').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {

Comment: `$('.edit:not(.editable-done)').addClass('editable-done').editable();
` after the `prepend()` call should do the job.

Comment: One more question why this happen..When I add regex function in html tags (which is feature of HTML5) in editable.js then this feature don't work why is it so mean html5 feature still lag dynamicaly